# Fastest Way to Loop through SQL Database column against Excel Column - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I have a sql table with two columns: OldValue and NewValue. I have the same two columns in an excel spreadsheet. I want to find the quickest way to iterate through both the database and excel spreadsheet checking if the OldValue column in the database is the same as the OldValue column in the spreadsheet.

My logic works such that I iterate the entire sql column (333228 records) looking for a match against the excel column which has 153 000 rows. This iteration is performance heavy and takes hours without even finishing - ends up hanging. How can I quickly do this? 153 000 x 333228 = 24 billion iterations which is computationally intensive.

I read here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47368/looping-through-an-excel-document-in-c but couldn't get what I was looking for. The code works and has already found 500 matches but its slow considering I need to get through 333228 records in the database.

```
 List<sim_info> exel_sims = new List<sim_info>();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel_app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks work_books = Excel_app.Workbooks;


            string excel_file_path = Application.StartupPath + "\\TestSample";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook work_book = work_books.Open(excel_file_path);
            work_book.SaveAs(excel_file_path + ".csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets work_sheets = work_book.Worksheets;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet work_sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)work_sheets.get_Item(1);



                for (int j = 2; j < work_sheet.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        temp_sim_info.msisdn = cell_to_str(work_sheet.Cells[j, 1]).Trim();
                        temp_sim_info.mtn_new_number = cell_to_str(work_sheet.Cells[j, 8]).Trim();
                        temp_sim_info.status = cell_to_str(work_sheet.Cells[j, 9]).Trim();

                        if (temp_sim_info.msisdn.Length < 5 || temp_sim_info.mtn_new_number.Length > 15) //Valid cellphone number length contains 11 digits +27XXXXXXXXX / 14 digits for the new msisdn. This condition checks for invalid cellphone numbers
                        {
                            if (zero_count++ > 10)
                                break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            zero_count = 0;

                            exel_sims.Add(temp_sim_info);
                            if (exel_sims.Count % 10 == 0)
                            {
                                txtExcelLoading.Text = exel_sims.Count.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        if (zero_count++ > 10)
                            break;
                    }

                    // }


                    txtExcelLoading.Text = exel_sims.Count.ToString();
                    work_sheet.Columns.AutoFit();

                    for (int i = 0; i < TestTableInstance.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string db_oldNumbers = "";
                        string db_CellNumber = "";

                        if (!TestTableInstance.Rows[i].IsNull("OldNumber"))
                            db_oldNumbers = TestTableInstance[i].OldNumber;
                        else
                            db_oldNumbers = TestTableInstance[i].CellNumber;
                        if (!TestTableInstance.Rows[i].IsNull("CellNumber"))
                            db_CellNumber = temp_sim_info.mtn_new_number;

                        for (int k = 0; k < exel_sims.Count; k++)
                        {

                                sim_info sim_Result = exel_sims.Find(x => TestTableInstance[i].CellNumber == x.msisdn);

                                    if (TestTableInstance[i].CellNumber ==    exel_sims[k].msisdn && sim_Result != null)
                                    {
                                       //If match found then do logic here
                                    }
                         }
                  }
        }
        MessageBox.show("DONE");
```

TableInstance is a DataSet of the database loaded in memory. The second inner loop iterates the entire DB column for each record until it finds a match in the first row of the OldValue column in the spreadsheet.

**My code works**. *Its tried and tested when I have an excel sheet of 800 rows and a DB table consisting of 1000 records. It completes under 5 minutes. But for hundred thousand records it hangs for hours*.

Comment: Why don't you load the Excel in SQL and run a simple query against it?

Comment: you tagged this both mysql and sql-server. Which is it ? And is a database tab needed here since you got the resultset in a dataset anyway ?

Comment: @Jens Load the excel in Sql using bulk copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly!  Why the heck are you use C# for this?  Load the Excel file into a temp table in your DB and do a comparison between your actual SQL table (which allegedly has all the data you have in the Excel file) and the temp table (or View).  This kind of comparison should complete in a couple seconds.

```
select * 
from dbtest02.dbo.article d2
left join dbtest01.dbo.article d1 on d2.id=d1.id
```

The left join shows all rows from the left table "dbtest02.dbo.article", even if there are no matches in the "dbtest01.dbo.article":

OR

```
select * from dbtest02.dbo.article
except
select * from dbtest01.dbo.article
```

See the link below for some other ideas of how to do this.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I copied the data to a virtual table in SQL using the Import Wizard, then ran your left join and in a matter of seconds, I was happy.

Comment: Want to mark that as the answer that helped you?  Just give it an up-vote and click the check mark too.